I used ctrl+v for a macro, now i can't turn it back to the regular paste
I used the keyboard shortcut ctrl+v for a macro, now i deleted the file that has the macro and can't turn it back to the regular paste.
When i use it, this is the error shown



Excel retains the shortcut settings even if you delete the host file (which has the VBA code).

Use below code to reset the setting.


Microsoft documentation:

Application.OnKey method (Excel)

Sub ResetShortcut()
    Application.OnKey "^v"
End Sub

